# Deepspeed with Pytorch library hostname -I error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, runtime-error, hostname

I am trying to setup a Neural network through the Deepspeed framework and Pytorch.

I cannot get over this error and the internet is not helping very much... Someone saw this before? (Complete log: https://hastebin.com/ugeciyujid.sql)

```
'"hostname -I"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Here is a code sample to reproduce:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=3, out_channels=1):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_channels, 12)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(12, 24)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(24, out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return self.relu(x)


import deepspeed
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

from model import SimpleModel


def setup():
    model = SimpleModel()

    arguments = {
        "train_batch_size": 1,
        "optimizer": {
            "type": "Adam",
            "params": {
                "lr": 5e-04
            }
        },
        "zero_optimization": "true"
    }

    engine, optimizer, _, _ = deepspeed.initialize(
        args=arguments,
        model=model,
        model_parameters=model.parameters()
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

My setup is python 3.8, a GTX 1060 6GB and torch 1.9 with cuda 11.1.